# Excel adding values from one sheet to another by formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have a list (**Sheet 1**) on Excel that looks like this:

```
Name    Phone
A       1432
B       4312
C       5321
D       1232
E       2543
F       3452
```

And I am making a separate list (**Sheet 2**) where there are some values of

```
Name    Phone   Department
D               asdsad
F               sdfsad
B               sdfsdf
A               sdfsdfsa
R               asdf
E               sdfs
Q               fds
L               sfdsd
```

How can I use a function that if Column of `A` of **Sheet 1** and column `A` of Sheet 2 are the same then it would add the phone number in Column b of Sheet 2 so that it looks like below:

```
Name    Phone   Department
D       1232    asdsad
F       3452    sdfsad
B       4312    sdfsdf
A       1432    sdfsdfsa
R       NA      asdf
E       2543    sdfs
Q       NA      fds
L       NA      sfdsd
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge multiple Excel workbooks based on key column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068658/merge-multiple-excel-workbooks-based-on-key-column)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just `VLOOKUP()` or `INDEX/MATCH`?

In Sheet2 B2,

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$100,2,FALSE)
```

or

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100,0))
```